# Maven: different java compiler versions for project and plugin

Tags: java, maven

We have a Java 7 project which uses a plugin built with Java 8. Is it possible to use the Java 8 plugin in Java 7 pom by setting the compiler version to use only for the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I just found that on the internet :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

You should just add a configuration section specifying the jdk wanted as

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.4</source>
      <target>1.4</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible, if the plugin forks into a new JVM process and allows you to configure the JVM which it uses to execute. Otherwise it will use the JVM, which the whole build uses. You would then have to run the build with a JRE/JDK 8 (which shouldn't be a problem when you set the source and target version appropriately, like in the answer from Juan Wolf (just set 1.7 instead of 1.4)